# JS setInterval() function does not fire correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm new in JS and I'm debugging a piece of code I did not write.
I'm working on a project where we need to handle a number of deal-based offers. Each deal element in the DOM has a personal expiration time which we track with a countdown timer. 
The following is the html page (a Django template) containing the timer:

```
<div class="countdown">
    <span class="countdown-time" data-remaining="{{ running_time }}"></span>
        {% if deal.is_normal %}
            <i class='fa fa-gavel'></i>
        {% elif deal.is_group%}
            <i class='fa fa-users'></i>
        {% elif deal.is_booking %}
            <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i>
        {% endif %}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayRange(seconds) {
        if (seconds <= 0) {
            return 'expired';
        }
        var count = seconds;

        hours = Math.floor(count/(60 * 60));
        count = count - hours * (60 * 60);

        minutes = Math.floor(count/60);
        seconds = count - minutes * 60;

        return sprintf("%02d", hours) + ':' + sprintf("%02d", minutes) + ":" + sprintf("%02d", seconds);
    }

    $('.countdown-time').each(function(index, el) {

        var that = $(this);
        var _el = el;

        var intervalID = setInterval(function() {

            var remaining = parseInt(_el.getAttribute('data-remaining'));
            var delta = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000) + remaining;

            console.log(' delta ' + delta +' remaining= ' + remaining + ' that=' + that + ' _el ' + _el + ' index ' + index);

            that.html(displayRange(remaining));

            _el.setAttribute('data-remaining', remaining - 1);

            if(remaining < 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        }, 1000);        
    });
</script>
```

The *setInterval* function should be called once per second per

```
$('.countdown-time').each(function(index, el) {
```

each DOM element with class *"countdown-time"*. 
What I expect is the countdown timer to step each second and to show the result in the corresponding deal element layout.

For each element with *index*, what happens instead is that *setinterval()* fires in parallel

```
total_number_of_deal_elements_in_the_DOM - index
```

times per second. So, for example, if I have in total 5 deal elements (*total_number_of_deal_elements_in_the_DOM* = 5), the deal element with *index = 1* has the countdown timer stepping 4 seconds per *setinterval* loop, because setInterval(function(....), 1000) is called in parallel 4 times per second. The index=2 element timer has a step of 3 seconds, and so on.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Use a single timer, with the checking loop inside it's callback. You do not need one timer per item as "a second is a second" regardless of how many times you measure it :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not know if I understand right. The countdown timer is different per each deal element because each deal has its own expiration time (each offer has a different duration in time, one could last 20 minutes and another 3 hours). Could you explain more what you suggest?

Comment: A single timer gives you an elapsed second. You then countdown each item until they reach 0. Leaving the time running is not a huge overhead, (much better than loads if timers all running) but you could shut it down when all counters hit 0. If you can mock up a working example of your code (e.g. JSFiddle) I will implment my suggestion.

Comment: The problem has been solved by assigning to each deal element a unique class ( <span class="countdown-time-{{deal.pk}}"), that actually makes the class an id tag. In this way, the js script is called only once per element. Thank you for your help, as soon as the project is complete, I will improve the timer implementation.